# OpenVZ VMs redirect to main node?

Tags: centos, ssh, centos6, openvz

I have a new fresh CentOs 6 machine and have SoulsVM and OpenVz installed on it.

When I create VPS it came online with no problem.

When I try to SSH to the VPS it gave me "Access Denied."

I reset the password 10 times and each time I got the same message.

I tried to use the main node password and it logged me in to the main node not the VM itself.

```
Linux xxx.xxx.xxx 2.6.32-042stab061.2 #1 SMP Fri Aug 24 09:07:21 MSK 2012                                                                                                                                                              x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Here is my GRUB file:

```
# grub.conf generated by anaconda
#
# Note that you do not have to rerun grub after making changes to this file
# NOTICE:  You have a /boot partition.  This means that
#          all kernel and initrd paths are relative to /boot/, eg.
#          root (hd0,1)
#          kernel /vmlinuz-version ro root=/dev/sda3
#          initrd /initrd-[generic-]version.img
#boot=/dev/sda
default=0
timeout=5
#splashimage=(hd0,0)/grub/splash.xpm.gz
#hiddenmenu
title OpenVZ (2.6.32-042stab061.2)
        root (hd0,1)
        kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-042stab061.2 ro root=/dev/sda4 crashkernel=auto SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 LANG=en_US.UTF-8 KEYTABLE=us
        initrd /initramfs-2.6.32-042stab061.2.img
title CentOS (2.6.32-279.5.2.el6.x86_64)
        root (hd0,1)
        kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-279.5.2.el6.x86_64 ro root=/dev/sda4 crashkernel=auto SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 LANG=en_US.UTF-8 KEYTABLE=us
        initrd /initramfs-2.6.32-279.5.2.el6.x86_64.img
title CentOS (2.6.32-220.7.1.el6.x86_64)
        root (hd0,1)
        kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-220.7.1.el6.x86_64 ro root=/dev/sda4 crashkernel=auto SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 LANG=en_US.UTF-8 KEYTABLE=us
        initrd /initramfs-2.6.32-220.7.1.el6.x86_64.img
title CentOS Linux (2.6.32-71.29.1.el6.x86_64)
        root (hd0,1)
        kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-71.29.1.el6.x86_64 ro root=/dev/sda4
        initrd /initramfs-2.6.32-71.29.1.el6.x86_64.img
title CentOS (2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64)
        root (hd0,1)
        kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64 ro root=/dev/sda4
        initrd /initramfs-2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64.img
```

Answer (score 0):

You could say

```
  vzctl enter id
```

If you want to ssh in then you must have set up your bridge or veth: you could share the details of this.